# nth-of-type does not work in less

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, less

I am styling a website and I need to apply some additional positioning due to the weird positioning (or different sizes?) of fontawesome icons.

This is the relevant html code:

```
<div class="footer-social">
    <div class="social-button"><span class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></span></div>
    <div class="social-button"><span class="fa fa-twitter fa-3x"></span></div>
    <div class="social-button"><span class="fa fa-linkedin fa-3x"></span></div>
</div>
```

and here the relevant less code:

```
.footer-social {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 73.5rem;
        margin-top: 8rem;
        .social-button {
            width: 4.3rem;
            height: 4.3rem;
            background-color: @accentColor;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-left: 10px;
            display: inline-block;
            span {
                line-height: 4.3rem;
                position: relative;
                left: 11px;
                &:nth-of-type(2) {
                    left: 8px;
                }
                &:nth-of-type(3) {
                    left: 9px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The second and third spans are not adjusting to the additional position I gave them. What am I missing here?

Comment: wouldn't that mean the second span within social button? - in which case there is only one

Comment: The problem is not with your Less code, it should compile just fine. It doesn't work because your HTML structure doesn't match the Less selectors. Within `.social-button` you have only one `span`. So your second span style never gets applied. You need to modify your Less selector structure like [here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/zmetq). *Note:* I added some dummy  values. Please check if this solves your problem.

Comment: yes, that worked, hanks! Seems weird to me to put span again on a different line after declaring nth-of-type (havent seen it before)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no problems with your Less code and as-such it should compile pretty fine. The problem rather is because your HTML structure doesn't match with the selectors generated by Less.

Your current code looks for the 2nd element and 3rd element of type `span` within the `.social-button` element and then tries to style them. That will work only when all the three `span` tags are within the same `.social-button` tag like below.

```
<div class="footer-social">
    <div class="social-button"> 
        <span class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x">a</span>
        <span class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x">b</span>
        <span class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x">c</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

For your actual HTML structure, you would actually need to apply the styles to the `span` tag under the 2nd and 3rd elements with class as `social-button`. Hence your Less structure should be modified as below. (**Note:** I have just used some sample properties just for illustration).

```
.social-button {
    span {
        color: red;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(2) span {
        background-color: beige;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(3) span {
        background-color: pink;
    } 
}
```

This [**demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/aADbx) would give a small visual illustration on the difference between the two selectors and how they work depending on your HTML structure.

Comment: What about a tiny [reduction](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/02fa31f62914be16dd7c#file-25936417-less)?

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Yup definitely. Initially started adding extra properties to the 2nd and 3rd `div` but then removed it for simplicity but forgot to remove the extra lines :)

Comment: Techincally it could be even something like [that](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/02fa31f62914be16dd7c#file-25936417-2-less), but this one would be an overkill I guess (too confusing for an unprepared reader :)

Comment: Exactly. Simpler for an experienced reader but would take time for a novice to grasp.